# Video .mov or .mp4 <video> tag HTML5 cannot be played on Safari Ipad/ Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a server that run Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.
I created a website that plays the .mov and .mp4 video on that server through Safari on iPad. The site works fine on my laptop browser, videos are playing well, but on iPad it only shows a round play button with a slash and is not clickable like this:
[enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/cubbgbd2z/)

I have searched for solutions but nothing seems to work. I guess there is a problem with my server because when I embedded a video from the internet, it worked fine on my iPad too.
What should I config to my server. Thank you very much and sorry about my bad english!